# Dialogs OData Set name?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, odata, crm, jscript

Ok in crm 2011 using Odata Query - if a workflows Odata Set name is AsyncOperationSet What is the equivalent for a dialog?

I have tried to figure this out with no luck

Please help

Thank you

P.s I need to get the dialogs id from its name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When searching for a dialog to launch via javascript:

Category = 1 (Dialog)
Type = 1 (Definition) - This is important if trying to call a dialog from javascript!

Solution:

```
triggerDialog = function (name, entityName, recordId) {

var dialogId = "";

    var request = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl() + "/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/WorkflowSet?$select=Name,WorkflowId&$filter=Type/Value eq 1 and Category/Value eq 1 and Name eq '"+name+"'";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        url: request,
        async: false,
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) {
            XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
            if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
                dialogId = data.d.results[0].WorkflowId;  
           }
        },
        error: function (XmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            /*Error Occurred*/
        }
    });

var serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();

window.showModalDialog(
serverUrl + "/cs/dialog/rundialog.aspx?DialogId=" + encodeURIComponent(dialogId) + "&EntityName=" + encodeURIComponent(entityName) + "&ObjectId=" + encodeURIComponent(recordId), null, "dialogHeight:600px;dialogWidth:800px;center:yes; resizable:1;maximize:1;minimize:1;status:no;scroll:no");
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information. [AsyncOperation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328118.aspx) is not instances of workflows only. It could be anything that is executed asynchronously (async plugins, calculating of matchcodes for dupdetection rules and many other).

Not sure what exactly do you want to get from Odata. What exactly do you need to get? If you need an instance of dialog - you will need to use AsyncOperation as well.

Comment: Ok thanks, well basically im firing the dialog via function: var serverUrl = SDK.JQuery._getServerUrl();

    window.showModalDialog(
    serverUrl + "/cs/dialog/rundialog.aspx?DialogId=" + encodeURIComponent(dialogId) + "&EntityName=" + encodeURIComponent(entityName) + "&ObjectId=" + encodeURIComponent(recordId), null, "dialogHeight:600px;dialogWidth:800px;center:yes; resizable:1;maximize:1;minimize:1;status:no;scroll:no");

However I am trying to query the id from the workflows name before rather then passing a static guid

Comment: If its included in AsyncOperationSet what would the System Job Type be?

Comment: If you want to get Id of dialog based on name you should use Workflow entity. To get proper OData query I would suggest you to use [OData query builder](http://crm2011odatatool.codeplex.com/)